# Do BigQuery queries run faster at night?

Tags: google-bigquery

I just received this from Google Support, and it surprised me as I didn't know there was a congestion issue - do other people have this experience?

> To fasten up your query, I would recommend that you try to run your query in other time like midnight

Comment: Are you/your company (not sure what your background is) using a flat-rate reservation? Or are you just doing on-demand/pay-as-you-go pricing?

Comment: Vanilla on-demand

Comment: It sounds like their suggestion is based on your queries needing more than 2000 slots to execute quickly. Running the queries during a time of day when there are more slack resources available means that you can potentially scale beyond 2000.

Comment: Ah, I had thought there was a limit at 2000 (that's what it says here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas). Good to know

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BigQuery is nocturnal, so it runs better in the dark. There are fewer predators around, so BigQuery can be free to express itself and cavort across the prairies near the Google Datacenters.

Other techniques to "enfasten" the queries involve running them from the ley lines of power, which are described in the Alchemical diaries of Hermes Trismagistus. Unfortunately, I am not permitted to share their location, and may be putting myself at risk of excommunication from a number of secret societies by just mentioning their existence.

Finally, if you name your tables with the suffix __Turbo, BigQuery will run them in turbo mode, which means they run on 486/66 processors instead of the default Z80 datapath.

---

Edited to add:
In a non-snarky answer, if you do not have reserved BigQuery capacity (i.e. fixed-price reservations), you may experience lower throughput at certain times. BigQuery has a shared pool of resources, so if lots of other customers are using it at the same time, there may not be enough resources to give everyone the resources that their queries would need to run at full speed.

That said, BigQuery uses a very large pool of resources, and we (currently) run at a utilization rate where every user gets nearly all of the resources they need nearly all of the time.

If you are seeing your queries slow down by 20% at certain times of the day, this might not be surprising. If you see queries take 2 or 3 times as long as they usually do, there is probably something else going on.